# How can I change the jquery Datepicker format when using a rails form_for helper method?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker, form-for

I am using Ruby On Rails 6.

Relevant Gems:

- gem 'active_scaffold', '~> 3.6.0.rc1'
- gem 'jquery-rails'
- gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

View looks like:

```
 <%= form_for(@tdn) do |f| %>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <%= f.label :pop_begin,"Start Date:" %>
          <%= f.text_field :pop_begin, class: 'date_picker' %>
        </div>
<% end # form_for %>
```

This generates a Datepicker, which works great, but users want the date formatted mm/dd/yyyy and default is yyyy/mm/dd.

Do I need to include a small javascript snippet outside the helper, or is there a helper attribute I set to format the date?

```
<%= f.text_field :pop_begin, class: 'date_picker', some_format_option: 'mm/dd/yyyy' %>
```

or

```
<script>
  js_function(SOMEVALUEA1, SOMEVALUEA2);
</script>
```

Comment: Did you know most browsers now support the HTML5 date input? You might as well switch and get rid of all the JQ datepicker issues and also jquery ui.

Comment: Thanks.  I did try that, and it works.  But sill having issues with the control of the widget, which is browser dependent.  ```<%= f.text_field :pop_end, type: 'date', required_pattern: "\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}" %>```

Comment: Afaik the date should be always sent as yyyy-mm-dd but the display format indeed differs based on locale. I have like 40 date fields in a reporting application and it always works just fine.

Comment: @DBulgatz Try `<%= form.date_field :pop_begin %>`